# Laptop boots into Windows after restarting from Linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So, the problem is this, when I start my laptop, I am able to choose to boot into either Linux or Windows. If I select Linux, then when I restart, it boots straight to Windows without presenting the grub screen to me at all. But if I select Windows, and restart, I am presented with a screen to select which OS I want to boot into. It always does that. How do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Disable the fast boot feature from Windows.

Comment: @MuaadElSharif it is not that

Comment: That means that Windows is the default OS in Grub, download Grub customizer and edit the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed BootRepair, and with just a few clicks, problem solved

Comment: did you mean boot repair?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh for some reason, I mis-spelled Boot Repair